# Deleting cookies to allow IE to log in

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, tankauth

I am using Tank Auth authentication library with Codeigniter 2.0.3 (one version before the current latest version) to create a log in page for my website. After a successful login, the user will be redirected to page X. However, if a user were to access page X directly without logging in, some code in the Controller for page X will redirect the user back to the log in page.

**Problem:** Many users using IE (IE8 included) have difficulty signing in. Even though they are successfully authenticated (i assume!) when they sign in from the sign in page, upon reaching page X, they get redirected back to the original sign in page. Sometimes, deleting the cookies will allow them to log in again.

I also tried increasing the `sess_expiration` in the config file to way higher than 7200, something like 720000 and more IE browsers can log in successfully.

Is this a bug with tank auth, or Codeigniter sessions?

Comment: did you ever make any progress on this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this would be the real answer but I try to use CI own session tool to set and unset sessions. In this way I don't need any authentication library no more. It's true it has some benefits but I think keep tracking the user login information is easy to handle with setting sessions by hand.